# Apply Outer to list of matrices and vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list, `M`, of square $ n \times n $ matrices, `{M1, M2, M3, ...}`, and a list, `V`, of $ n \times 1 $ vectors, `{v1, v2, v3, ...}`, and the corresponding transposes of those vectors `{r1, r2, r3, ...}`. I'm trying to form the matrix
`{{r1.M1.v1, r2.M1.v2, r3.M1.v3, ...}, {{r1.M2.v1, r2.M2.v2, r3.M2.v3, ...}, ...}`. Note that `M` and `V` are not necessarily the same length (i.e. there may only be 5 matrices, but 100 vectors).

It seemed like a method using `Outer` would work, such as: `Outer[Transpose[#2].#1.#2 &, M, V]`, which should then just be a 2-dimensional matrix of scalars.

However, I think that this runs into a problem because the lists `M` and `V` are themselves technically lists of lists (`M` being a list of matrices, `V` being a list of vectors), and so the outer gets distributed into the sublists, rather than doing the calculation I want and it ends up being a high dimensional object. I've tried playing around with various flattening schemes, but haven't quite figured it out - any assistance on how to implement this functionality (is `Outer` even the correct functional tool to use)?

Comment: I believe what you want is `Outer[#2.#1.#2 &, M, V, 1, 1]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you want is

```
Outer[#2.#1.#2 &, M, V, 1]
```

First of all, you don't need to `Transpose` vectors in *Mathematica*.  `Dot` knows what to do automatically.  Second, you need to use the optional extra argument for `Outer` that tells it the level at which the "object" that you are feeding to the function lives.  Otherwise, `Outer` seeks the lowest level by default.  Since your "objects" are at level 1 in both lists (the elements of the lists which are either matrices or vectors), use the level-spec 1 as the extra argument to `Outer`.

Comment: Ah ok. My problem is that my vectors V are defined as column vectors, i.e. ``v1={{1},{0},{0},{0}}``. So I think that was screwing up the Outer. Flattening them does indeed work as you show. However, is there a way to work with the V as I had defined previously? It would be more convenient, as long as it would be much more complicated.

Comment: @KHAAAAAAAAN In that case, I think do `Flatten /@ Outer[Transpose[#2].#1.#2 &, M, V, 1]`?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Table`

```
SeedRandom@12;
m = Table[RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}], 3];
MatrixForm /@ m
```

> m=$\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  5 & 4 \\
>  1 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  5 & 3 \\
>  0 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\}$

```
v = Table[RandomInteger[5, 2], 3]
```

> v={{3, 4}, {1, 1}, {2, 5}}

```
Table[v[[j]].m[[i]].v[[j]], {i, Length@m}, {j, Length@m}]
```

> {{21, 2, 14}, {169, 14, 170}, {161, 13, 175}}

**Second Solution**

```
#2.#1.#2 & @@@ Tuples[{m, v}] // Partition[#, 3] &
```

Comment: Yeah this thought had occurred, but it seemed a less elegant solution than Outer, though of course still functional. That should be ``{j, Length@v}`` though I take it?

Comment: `Length@v=Length@m`

Comment: Well in general the list V and list M are not the same size for my use case, sorry that probably was not clear from my initial question.